# Visual c++ "doesn't see" sources .cpp file in unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I have a unit test C++ project, and it compiles and runs without issues if all code is in header file. However, when I declare one property as static and take it's initialization to the .cpp file (with the same name), I get:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol: public static class...

Any suggestions how to ensure visual studio finds and compiles .cpp file? They are both in the same directory and this directory in the include list.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: I'm supposing that you have already added the .cpp files to your project? did you?

Comment: If the source files are in another project (e.g.) you have to link the other project to your unit test project. this is of course only possible if the project to be tested is a library / dll. If it is an exe project, you should move the functional parts, you want to test, into a library project and use this library in both the unit tests and your exe project.

Comment: The unit test project is referencing header files as External Dependencies, and both items (.h and .cpp) are added in the solution items.